# is it possible to get all lines of a file in svn diff when it has no change in it

Tags: git, svn

Is it possible to take svn diff for a file which does not have any change in it.

Actually i have a program that creates a svn diff to html view. I want to include that file in the html. But since the file has no change in it. It is now showing in svn st. And also not coming up in html view.

This command gives all the lines in the file if at lease there is one change in the file.

```
svn diff abc.file --diff-cmd=diff -x -U500
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No, your command using `diff -x -U500` does NOT show an entire file if there is at least one change. And no, you cannot show a diff of a file that has no changes. A diff is a view of the changes, not a view of the file.

I'm not sure what the `-x` is doing, documentation says it should "exclude files that match PAT" but you give no pattern.

The `-U500` is saying to give 500 lines of context around every change. Thus if you have one change in the first line of a 2000-line file, most of the file will be omitted.

Probably you actually are looking for `svn cat` which can show you the full text of any file in any revision. Or perhaps you really want `svn blame` which can show you an entire file with annotations of what revision last changed every line of code. `svn blame` can even take a revision or revision range, if you're only interested in showing this information for recently changed files.